# How to send whatsApp message to any number by using twilio using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am new to Twilio

below is my code to send whatsapp message using C#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
        TwilioClient.Init(Model.AccountSid, Model.AuthToken);
       
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
           
           //whatsapp message 
           to: new PhoneNumber(Model.To), from: new PhoneNumber(Model.From),
           body: "Ahoy from Twilio!!!!!"
         );
        
        Console.WriteLine("Message SID: " + message.Sid);
    }
```

Model.To have my whatsapp number which I have used while registering with twilio.

Model.From have Twilio's WhatsApp number

if I run this console application then I get message on my whatsapp number

but when I try to send message to my friend's WhatsApp number by assigning that number to Model.To,
I am not getting message on that number

How can I achieve it?
is there any other way to achieve it without twilio?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Trial account then

1)first verify that number from here https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified

2)after verifying the number ,send whatsapp message from verified number to the twilio's whatsapp number using your sandbox code (code will be like e.g join XYZ-PQR)

3)after sending the whatsapp message that number will join your sandbox and you will be able to send message on that number

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Twilio [Debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=72) for errors. If you are sending the first message from Twilio out to the WhatsApp user, you must initially use a Template, as detailed [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates).

Comment: I am getting whatsapp message on my number ,but if I try to send message on my friend's whatsapp number that time message is not going to that number and debugger also not showing any error.

Comment: Check the API response as well as the Messaging Logs, https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs,  to see what the error is.

Comment: I am  getting this error message -(Error: 63015) Channel Sandbox can only send messages to phone numbers that have joined the Sandbox.

Comment: So if you are using the Twilio WhatsApp Sandbox, you need to have your friend join your sandbox before you can send them a message. You did the same with your own mobile device when you started using the Sandbox. When you get a production WhatsApp number, you use approved templates to reach out to WhatsApp users and they don't need to join first.

Comment: ok..Thanks for the information.. can u guide me on how multiple numbers can use same sandbox?..I have verfied 2 numbers for my sandbox ..but at a time communication with only one number is possible with my trial account.

Comment: This page, https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox, shows you the `join` command and modifier and number they need to send to in order for you to send them a message. Note that there is a 24 hour window for free-form communication (on their last inbound message), then you need to send from one of the templates shown on the same page.